# "Start make the changing " vs " Start making the change"

Tags: gerunds, verb-forms, auxiliary-verbs

Which one is correct?

> You can start **making the changes** in your design.

or

> You can start **make changing** in your design.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?  Have you found any examples of either of them?  It might suggest something that ["you can start make"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+can+start+make%22) returns five results, and ["you can start making"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+can+start+making%22) returns about 5,940.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence (*making the changes*) is correct, because the changes are the things being made.

Because the changes are things, they must be nouns. It can then be determined that your second sentence (*making changing*) is not correct because "changing" is the gerund form of the verb.

Comment: English is so weird, I can think of several tiny changes in the wording that drastically alter the meaning. Some of them have multiple meanings themselves. Gives me compassion for ell's.